# Angular 4.2.4 : Unable to retrieve JSON

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm struggling to retrieve JSON from a Rest API.
Here is my code

```js
getSports(): void {
    this.http.get(this.url,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Accept', 'application/json')
      }).subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
  }
```

null is printed to console. What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check your Developer's tool. What does your get request return?

Comment: Also check what the API is returning. It might be a malformed JSON.

Comment: Daniel, The response returned with a status 200. As I.R.R suggested the json was malformed. Now solved, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The response returned with a status 200. The issue I was having was that the json was malformed